# The name 'x' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've created a view 'Test.cshtml' and want to access a resource I created under ~/Content/i18n called 'Retailers'.  I have included the line:

```
<add namespace="MyProject.Content.i18n" />
```

in the \Views\Web.config of the project so I would expect the following code to work:

```
@{
    var x = Retailers.Intro;
}
```

but instead, the IDE red-underlines the word Retailers and advises the error message in the header of this post.

the weird thing is that in other views I can access other resources and I don't find any differences in the metadata as to why this would be.  if I add a new view I cannot access my resources...

the question: how can I troubleshoot this? what should I be looking at?

Comment: close and reopen visual studio (or unload/load project). I think the namespaces on web.config are loaded when the project is first loaded.

Comment: I've done that, as well as cleaned the solution and recompiled everything, without any success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I figured it out.  it's an Intellisense problem... in fact, in I just compile the code and run the application, everything is fine.  I pulled a lot of hair over this!